# how to access external hard disk files when ownership is on another OS?

Tags: permissions

i reinstalled ubuntu, and although accessible through

```
sudo -i
chmod 777 /media/b/hdd3
```

hdd3=2nd partition(name of label)

```
chown b:b /media/b/hdd3
```

if i go to a different having ubuntu or any linux distro will i be able to access my external hdd or will i lose access to all data, if so then the password of user=a will have to be stored on my hdd. or if i go to another CPU or OS will i have to use that OS password for sudo, or my old password.

Comment: it is perfectly clear what this user is asking

Answer (score 1):

short answer:

Unless the filesystem is encrypted, you should only have to use the password for sudo on the new OS. You should not have to use any old or previously used passwords unless the filesystem is encrypted.

Furthermore, you should not lose access. If anything, you may have to cuse `sudo` at the most. In rare cases, you will have to specify read write mode when you mount the device, although, that should not be an issue here.

Additionally, the drive is currently set to `777` which allows access to everyone anyhow.